# Can presentModalViewController be thought of as a way of a popup in ios applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar based application that needs to show certain views. There are certain "screens" that are not part of the tabs. In those cases is it wise to use presentModalViewController or just to "insert the view".

Any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use `presentModalViewController`. It's easier to write and maintain and the free animation provides extra feedback to the user. I don't see why you wouldn't want to use it.